# Cannot install expo-cli in windows - node version 14.17.6

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

I wanted to start learning React Native using Expo, but I cannot install it using npm.

When I run the command `npm install -g expo-cli`, it gives me the following error:

```
added 825 packages, and audited 826 packages in 53s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

10 vulnerabilities (4 low, 6 moderate)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

It told me to run `npm audit fix` and I tried the command right away.

However, the error stills seem to remain

```
# npm audit report

node-fetch  <=2.6.0 || 3.0.0-beta.1 - 3.0.0-beta.8
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/node-fetch
  isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbjs
      fbemitter  2.0.3 - 3.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/fbemitter
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
        Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
        node_modules/expo

xmldom  *
Severity: moderate
Misinterpretation of malicious XML input - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1769
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/xmldom
  @expo/plist  <=0.0.13
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xmldom
  node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/plist
    @expo/config-plugins  <=3.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/plist
    node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
      @expo/config  3.3.23-alpha.0 - 5.0.8
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
      node_modules/expo-constants/node_modules/@expo/config
        expo-constants  >=10.1.2
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
        node_modules/expo-constants
          expo  >=14.0.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
          Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
          node_modules/expo

10 vulnerabilities (4 low, 6 moderate)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I tried running `npm audit fix --force` and it gave me the following outcome.

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating expo to 1.0.0,which is a SemVer major change.

removed 824 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 19s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I thought it worked and I tried running the command `expo` and `expo-cli` and bash told me that the command could not be found.

Comment: In NPM, "vulnerabilities" are important because they can make your code vulnerable to attacks and exploits, but they won't keep your application from running or anything. As such, there's no actual "error" in your first code block, just a warning that there are known vulnerabilities in some of the included packages. You can read more about npm audit and what it does [here](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/npm-audit/).

Comment: As for moving forward, running `npm audit fix --force` _did_ possibly break something, because of that warning it gave you in your third block: "*Updating expo to 1.0.0, which is a SemVer major change.*". I would advise you to remove your `node_modules` folder and reinstall your packages fresh. You're welcome to run `npm audit fix`, which is designed specifically not to break anything, but beyond that, you shouldn't run into any actual problems related to that warning.